# RxJS Observable replace stream with new data

Tags: rxjs

I have a service which updates an observable's data upon initialization, and then upon a http search.

Using next() adds records to the array in the observable, but how would I go about replacing those records with a new set?

search.service.ts

```
 private searchSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.getInitialCollections());

    public currentState = this.searchSource.asObservable();

    public getInitialCollections() {
        return this.apiService.post(this.searchApi)
            .subscribe(data => this.changeSubject(data));
    }

    public search(phrase: string) {
        return this.apiService.post(this.searchApi, { phrase: phrase })
            .subscribe(data => this.changeSubject(data));
    }

    private changeSubject(results: object) {
        this.readCollectionResult(results).map(data => this.searchSource.next(data));
    }

    private readCollectionResult(result: any): Asset[] {
        return (result && result.data) ? result.data.map(asset => asset) : [];
    }
```

component.ts

```
export class SearchDataSet {
    /** Stream that emits whenever the data has been modified. */
    dataChange: BehaviorSubject<Asset[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Asset[]>([]);
    get data(): Asset[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

    constructor(
        private _searchService: SearchService
    ) {
        this.initialize();
    }

    records = this.data.slice();

    initialize() {
        this._searchService.currentState
            .subscribe(item => !item.id ? null : this.addRecord(item));
    }

    /** Adds a new asset to the database. */
    addRecord(item: object) {
        this.records.push(item);
        this.dataChange.next(this.records);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'Using next() adds records to the array in the observable'

Actually since searchSource is a BehaviorSubject, it can only hold one value so `searchSource.next(data)` ***replaces*** the current content of searchSource with data.

You might want an additional method

```js
private addToSubject(results: object) {
  this.searchSource.subscribe(current => {
    const assets = this.readCollectionResult(results);
    this.searchSource.next(current.concat(assets));
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the behavior of items being added onto the array of results returned from the observable - when I call my search function, the results are simply those items appended onto the end of the currentState observable

Comment: Sorry, I had a note about readCollectionResult then realized you'd posted it, so changed the answer.

Comment: can you really do a current.push(assets) in the next function like that? I'll try this

Comment: I'll see if I can produce a test. You're sure the current value of `searchSource` is getting modified, you're not just seeing the next emitted value?

Comment: yea it's so strange, I'll post my component that is consuming the service

Comment: Actually, it should be `.concat()` - I had the wrong mental picture initially.

Comment: getting current.concat is not a function, I think I'm thinking too far into this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158358/discussion-between-iamwhitebox-and-richard-matsen).